# I need to implement Code editor for linux commands in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of Linux commands which should be displayed in a code editor I need to implement so that it looks colorful. The list of linux commands will be stored in a database. I am using AngularJS and I found Monaco Editor but this is for Angular 2 and above. Can you one please help me pointing me to an AngularJS editor.

```
<section class="col col-md-12">
         <label class="label">Installation Script</label>
         <textarea id="installScript" class="padding-10" 
              style="width:100%;height:100%;" rows="15"></textarea>
</section>
<section class="col col-md-12">
          <label class="label">Un-installation Script</label>
          <textarea id="unInstallScript" class="padding-10" 
              style="width:100%;height:100%;" rows="5"></textarea>
</section>

     js file

    var element = $('#installScript')[0];
        element.value = "Loading ...";
        var unelement = $('#unInstallScript')[0];
        unelement.value = "Loading ...";
        element.value = res.data;
```

element.value contain the Linux commands

[image]

Comment: Hi @girish, I'm sorry but I find your question a little ambiguous. Are you trying to find a text editor that you can code with? I've used Brackets and Atom with my AngularJS projects. Or are you trying to code/implement an editor of your own? If that's the case, you probably need to provide a bit more info and/or examples of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: here is the installation script in Linux commands is displayed to the user. i need some code editor so that is look's good currently its plain. 
i have add the code please check